# SilverStripe dev task is not found or registered in the list

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am developing a SilverStripe project. I am trying to create a task to run through accessing the `dev/tasks` URL but the task I have created is not showing up in the tasks list.

In the code folder I have created a file `SayHiTask` with the following code:

```php
class SayHiTask extends MigrationRecord
{
    protected $title = 'Say Hi';

    protected $description = 'A class that says <strong>Hi</strong>';

    protected $enabled = true;

    function run($request) {
        echo "I'm trying to say hi...";
    }
}
```

I then build the project again by visiting `dev/build?flush=all`. Then, when I go to `dev/tasks`, the task is not displayed in the list.

What is wrong and what did I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a custom build task we need to extend the `BuildTask` class:

```php
use SilverStripe\Dev\BuildTask;

class SayHiTask extends BuildTask
{
    protected $title = 'Say Hi';
    protected $description = 'A class that says Hi';
    protected $enabled = true;

    public function run($request)
    {
        echo "I'm trying to say hi...";
    }
}
```

Once we have this code we visit `dev/tasks?flush=all` and our `Say Hi` dev task will appear in the list of available tasks.

Comment: Hi yeah. Thanks for the answer. yeah, my code was extending the wrong class. Cheers